# array initialization, is referencing a previous element ok?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, standards

```
const QPointF points[] =
{
    QPointF(r.left() - i, r.top() - i),
    QPointF(r.right() + i, r.top() - i),
    QPointF(r.right() + i, r.bottom() + i),
    QPointF(r.left() - i, r.bottom() + i),
    points[0] // is this line valid (according to the C++ standard)?
};
```

While this compiles with the MS Visual Studio Compiler, i am not sure if this is valid code according to the C++ Standard.

Quotes from the Standard would be **highly appreciated.**

Comment: `g++ -pedantic` doesn't complain.

Comment: ... although it doesn't complain about `const int x = x;` either.

Comment: I would think that it's correct(points[0] refers to a valid object by that time), but I wouldn't know for sure. The grammar checks out, obviously, and flipping through Stroustroup just says "An array can be initialized by a list of values. points[0] is a value, so it seems correct.

Comment: @Dasuraga: No, `points[0]` does _not_ refer to a valid object "by that time". `points[0]` has an **indeterminate** value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>C++03/C++11 answer</sub>

---

No, it's not.

On the right-hand side of the `=`, `points` does exist<sup>1</sup> but the initialiser is only applied after all its operands have been evaluated.

- If `points` is at namespace scope (and thus has static storage duration and has been zero-initialized<sup>2</sup>), then this is "safe" but your use of `points[0]` there is going to give you `0`, rather than `QPointF(r.left() - i, r.top() - i)` again.
- If `points` has automatic storage duration — it has not yet been initialised so your use of `points[0]` is attempting to use an uninitialised variable, where `points[0]` has an indeterminate value... which is bad<sup>3</sup>.

It's difficult to provide standard references for this, other than to say that there is nothing in `8.5 "Initializers"` that explicitly makes this possible, and rules elsewhere fill in the rest.

---

> <sup>1</sup> `[n3290: 3.3.2/1]:` **The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator** (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> int x = 12;
> { int x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second `x` is initialized with its own **(indeterminate)** value. *—end example* ]
>
> <sup>2</sup> `[n3290: 3.6.2/2]:` Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
>   before any other initialization takes place. [..]
>
> <sup>3</sup> `[n3290: 17.6.3.3/2]:` [..] [ *Note:* Operations
>   involving indeterminate values may cause undefined behavior. *—end note* ]

Comment: I didn't realize it was a valid alternative spelling :)

Comment: @EvilTeach: "Initialiser" is the correct English spelling. The "alternative" with a "z" is found in an offshoot of English, known as "American English". I believe there a few people in parts of the continent of North America who adhere to this modified lexicon.

Answer (score 2):

from http://www.comeaucomputing.com/pcgi-bin/compiler.cgi:

```
Copyright 1988-2008 Comeau Computing.  All rights reserved.
MODE:strict errors C++ C++0x_extensions

"ComeauTest.c", line 8: warning: variable "points" is used before its value is set
      points[0] // is this line valid (according to the C++ standard)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) in the statement, the result is undefined, much like for the `i=i++` example quoted at that wikipedia page.

Otherwise said, nothing specifies, whether the compiler should first evaluate everything, then assign, or do evaluate-assign for each element separately and in which order.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why I didn't think of that. Potentially a much simpler way to describe the scenario.

Comment: At least the order in which the initializers for each element are evaluated is specified.

Comment: @smerlin: why do you think so? The comma in `{.., ..}` is not the "comma operator" in this context. (Similar to the wikipedia article referenced, sub pt. 4: "Note that a function call f(a,b,c) is not a use of the comma operator and the order of evaluation for a, b, and c is unspecified.")

Comment: @eudoxos: While the quote of the standard in my answer does not cover the OPs question, it covers this - and it says that the order is specified.

Answer (score -2):

**Old Answer (misses the point):**

I checked the current C++0x draft, and there i found the sentence 8.5.1.17 which says:

> 17 The full-expressions in an
>   *initializer-clause* are evaluated in
>   the order in which they appear.

So while this sentence is not part of the C++ Standard from 2003, im quite sure that this should be working in any up to date compiler, if this is part of C++0x.

**Edit:**
The comments made me rethink this matter. This line only ensures that the `QPointF` objects are created in the order in which they occur in the array initialization (relevant if the element constructors have observable side-effects). The problem is, the value of `points` is indeterminate during its array initialization. So there cant be a guarantee for a valid value of `points[0]` either, at least not if you rely on the standard.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant at all.

Comment: Right, although evaluation must precede assignment, it does not say when are the values *assigned*, which is what matters here.

Comment: @eudoxos: Yes you are right, although only a single value is assigned.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Thanks for the hint, i only considered the order of initialization in the array initialization clause itself :/